# How to run Aggregation tests in spring-data-mongodb repo against My MongoURL Connection String?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

For this github repo - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/tree/main

I want to know how can I run just the aggregation tests by passing my Connection String. There is nothing mentioned in the document.

The Connection URL is mentioned at multiple places in the code. Do I need to change everywhere or there is a centralised config file where I can make the changes?